# How to get the second set of white spaces within a string using the string.split(" ") Js

Tags: javascript

I have a string will have atleast one whitespace, in that case its easier to use the

`string.split(" ")` to get 2 elements in an array.
Ex:

```
var string = "ABC123 JAck3939";
string.split(" ") // o/p: ["ABC123", "JAck3939"];
```

however there might be a case where I may have multiple spaces:
Ex:

```
var string = "ABC 123 JAck 123333"
```

In above case, I would still want to separate out:

```
"ABC 123" and "JAck 123333"
```

but using `string.split(" ")` will give me:

```
["ABC", "123", "JAck", "123333"]
```

instead Im trying to get 2 elements, one with `"ABC 123" and "JAck 123333"`
In this case I'm not worried about the spaces between `"ABC 123" and "JAck 123333"`

possible scenarios:

```
string = "ABC122 JACK333",
string = "ABC 122 JACK333",
string = "ABC 122 JACK 333",
string = "ABC122 JACK 333"
```

Here is the fiddle I have created:
https://jsfiddle.net/qdoLvhz3/32/

The reason I was trying to get these whitespaces eliminated was coz I wanted to get following in the o/p

```
Name: ABC
Id: 32423
Address: Jack
Code: 43453
```

Now a valid input field value will have

- letters+numbers (space) letters+numbers
- letters(space) numbers (space) letters (space) numbers
- letters+numbers (space) numbers+letters

so when a user types:

```
string = "something322somethingALL433"
```

this will be invalid string as there is no space between the first set of letters+numbers (i.e, "something322" and "somethingALL433")

Currently with my code when a user types: `string = "abd32xys6472"` the o/p I get is:

```
Name: abdxys
Id: 326472
```

Instead i try to get:

```
Name:abd
Id:32
Address:xys
Code:6472
```

hope this makes sense!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the desired logic is here - what if the input is `foo bar baz`, or with 4 spaces instead of 3, etc?

Comment: then the foo and bar will be together and baz as next element, i.e: ["foobar","baz"]

Comment: So it sounds like you not only want to match particular sections of the string, you also want to *replace* the whitespace in some matched sections (but not others)?

Comment: yea, that is true

Comment: that sounds like a *third* different way of handling things.  Can you give us the generalization that captures all the cases, including `'foo bar baz qux corg'` and `'a b c d e f g h i'`?

Comment: edited my answer to show possible scenarios, wont have other than (a b c d)

Comment: After you split it, get the length of the result, and concatenate the ones you want to keep together.

Comment: Are `"ABC 122 JACK333"` and `"ABC122 JACK 333"` both supposed to return `["ABC 123", "JAck 123333"`? If so, what is the criteria for combining the first two versus the last two?

Comment: @Barmar, the criteria is there is always going to be whitespace between "ABC122" and "JACK333", but there may or may not be space between "ABC" and "122" or "JACK" and "333" hence I want to split ideally all 4 of them and display them individually, but coz of this one or multiple whitespaces I'm trying to get the exact elements

Comment: That's not clear enough. When you have `x y z`, should the result be `xy z` or `x yz`?

Comment: @Barmar: have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to match a sequence of letters followed by a sequence of numbers, with optional whitespace between them.

```js
function get_strings(str) {
  var m = str.match(/([a-z]+\s*\d+)\s+([a-z]+\s*\d+|\d+\s*[a-z]+)/i);
  return m && m.slice(1);
}
console.log(get_strings("ABC122 JACK333"))
console.log(get_strings("ABC 122 JACK333"))
console.log(get_strings("ABC 122 JACK 333"))
console.log(get_strings("ABC122 JACK 333"))
console.log(get_strings("test444 444test"))
```

- `[a-z]+` matches a series of letters
- `\d+` matches a series of digits
- `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace characters
- `\s+` matches at least 1 whitespace character, which is required between the first and second parts of the string
- `|` separates alternatives -- this allows the second capture to be either letters+numbers or numbers+letters
- `()` surrounds capture groups, which are returned as additional elements of the array
- `i` makes the letter matching case-insensitive
- `m.slice(1)` discards the first element of the array, which is the entire match, so we just return what matched the capture groups.

Comment: thanks @barmar, worked like a charm, just a quick thing, there is also a scenario where it could be ```str="test444 444test"``` as mentioned above in my example. is there a way I can change the regex to match that scenario? thx

Comment: I've updated the answer to use two capture groups. The first group matches `letters+numbers`, the second matches either `letters+numbers` or `numbers+letters`.